# put pixel in area according the registration in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pixel

I need to create a figure (square) where for each client registered in the system, I put a pixel in a chosen location of the square by the client. I have this example . I need a hint in C # on how to get started.This is only exemple to start.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace RandomPixelImage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int width = 640, height = 320;
            //bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
            //random number
            Random rand = new Random();
            //create random pixels
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    //generate random ARGB value
                    int a = rand.Next(256);
                    int r = rand.Next(256);
                    int g = rand.Next(256);
                    int b = rand.Next(256);
                    //set ARGB value
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
                }
            }
            //load bmp in picturebox1
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            //save (write) random pixel image
            bmp.Save("D:\\Image\\RandomImage.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just need to know how to manipulate each pixel and put it in the drawing as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already made a Bitmap, all you need to do is assign that to PictureBox control:

First add a PictureBox control to your form, and then add this code to get your image onto it.

```
pictureBox.Image = bmp;
```

As your example shows, you can use Bitmap.SetPixel() to alter single pixels.

Comment: How can I do that? I want to show only one picture on pictureBox.

Comment: How can I show only a pixel, jump one cell and put another and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but you should be able to adjust any single pixel in the entire image. What do you mean by "jump one cell"?

Comment: Sorry, it should be : skip a cell